# Stack Snippet gets embedded twice now

Tags: support, stack-snippets

Seems like a myriad of changes to Stack Snippets happened recently. Two issues I've noticed just now are that some seem to be doubly-embedded:

[Facebook Custom Button Implementation Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761770/facebook-custom-button-implementation-issue)

And on top of that, when editing a post with a Stack Snippet, the Snippet isn't visible. I see a string and `<pre>` tags.

**Some previews to support**

[image: preview]

[image: prevoew]

(Is there somewhere I can read about the update(s) to the Stack Snippet feature that occurred recently?)

Comment: @Oded BTW, per my closing question, is there some post being maintained about Stack Snippet changes? The interface changed drastically again and there was no warning or notice that I could see.

Comment: I am not aware of such a post.

Comment: @Oded There is one on MSE which announced the changes. People, including me, have been using it as a place to mention bugs and related feature requests: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280250

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This just looks like some user confusing snippets and code blocks and using both buttons on it. If you use the snippet editor and don't muck about with the result, it works correctly.

I've edited the question to remove the indentation and to separate the end comments from the code with a blank line (as the snippet editor does), and the problem cleared up immediately.